# How can you test an Appcelerator Windows App on a Surface tablet?

Tags: appcelerator

I'm attempting to test an app built with TI SDK 5.4.0 GA on a Windows Surface tablet running Windows 10. I know 5.4.0 had loads of Windows 10 support but I didn't find any additional documentation on how to test on the more popular Windows devices like the Surface line. Windows 10 supports phone apps right?

As far as components, I've got Studio building and deploying the app to a Windows Emulator for 8.1 so I'm assuming I have most of the setup correct. This is where the existing documentation for Appcelerator got me but I'm not interested in Windows Phones, I'm interested in Windows tablets.

Does anyone have any experience with "mobile" (i.e. running on Android and iOS tablets) apps developed/tested/deployed on a Surface that can point me to the documentation I'm missing?

Surely I'm not the only one that had the surface in mind when I filled out the Appcelerator survey saying I'd like to see Windows support! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator Windows platform supports building the apps for phone and tablet.

Packaging an app for Windows tablet from Appcelerator Studio
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Deploying_to_Windows_Devices

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Distributing_Windows_Applications

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Windows_Platform_Overview-section-43308580_WindowsPlatformOverview-WindowsStore

Comment: Thank you, Kondal! Based on what you've provided, I don't see a way to test on a surface device without fully packaging the app. Is that accurate?